# Binary serialisation of Rust data strucutures

Tags: serialization, binary, rust

What is the current state of serialisation-to-binary in Rust?

I have some large (1-10MB) data structure to be sent across a network, and don't want to encode them as JSON or hex (the two serialisers I have found).

I have found `#[repr(packed)]`.  Is this what I should use, or is there something more portable?

Comment: It should be pretty easy to do this with either https://github.com/TyOverby/bincode or https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-cbor --- Both work with the standard `io::{Read,Write}` traits in addition to `rustc-serialize`'s `Encodable` and `Decodable` traits.

Comment: bincode is exactly what I was looking for.  If you make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I can't, because people who know better have apparently deemed this to be a bad question. (You asked, "What is the current state... ?" How this is "opinion-based" is far beyond my limited mental capacity to understand.)

Comment: @BurntSushi5: 1. Library recommendations are off-topic; 2. Picking one library among others can easily devolve into a battle of opinions. It's not that the question is "bad", it's that it is judged not to be a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: No part of the question asks for a library recommendation.

Answer (score 7):

`#[repr(packed)]` only makes your data small. It does not offer any format guarantees or serialization help.

You have a few choices here (ordered by my opinion from best to worst solution):

1. You can use the Cap'n proto implementation for Rust

   - https://github.com/dwrensha/capnproto-rust
   - It's not really serialization, more of a forced format for structs that are then sent over the network without any conversion
   - fast
2. You could write your own Serializer and Deserializer.

   - you have full control over the format
   - runtime overhead for every single datum
   - you need to implement lots of stuff
3. You can `transmute` your structs to a `[u8]` and send that

   - probably the fastest solution
   - you need to make sure that the compiler for the program on both sides is exactly the same, otherwise the formats don't match up.
   - Someone evil may send you bad data. When you `transmute` that back, you get buffer overflows and stuff
   - references in your data-structure will cause wild pointers and  undefined behaviour

     - Don't use references

Comment: `transmute` won't work not only with references, but with any types with indirection, like `String` or `Vec<_>`. In fact, it would work only with structs which consist of basic built-in types and fixed-size arrays of such types.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Would that simply be `Copy` types ?

Comment: @Levans, no - types with references also can be `Copy`. I'd say `Copy + 'static` is more like it, but `*const` pointers are also `Copy` AFAIK.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Oh right, indeed.